# How to set modal dialog title dynamically in oracle apex 18

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-18.2

I want to set modal dialog title dynamically based on an interactive element.

ex) In page 50, I've made an Interactive Grid and set the link on "Title" column, when user click on title column, a modal dialog appears.
I want to set the title of that modal dialog to title column's content.

But modal dialog's title doesn't change dynamically.
In this case, how can I apply the titles dynamically?

I've seen many solution related to this question, but I can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, your model page number is 51. Here are step by step approach [TESTED] to dynamically change title of model page:

1. Create a hidden item in your model page, let's say the hidden item name is P51_Title.
2. In Interactive report -> title column link -> click on link builder box -> set values -> add Hidden item as P51_TITLE under Name and value as '#Title#' Column (#ColumnName#).
3. In model page 51 static region header (title property), add hidden item value as &P51_TITLE. (dot is mandatory to add at last. This is substitution string with & and dot(.) before and after of item name respectively)

save both the pages and run. when you will click on title column link, the link will be redirecting to the model page and title data will be passed through URL to hidden item in the session, so model page header will automatically change based on title data from report.

Comment: nooo I've already tried this approach, it doesn't work. It can't renew its content dynamically

Comment: Are you clearing the cache of your model page from Link Builder? The same approach is working in my case, and I could see the values of title column appearing in model page header title.

Comment: Tested this, (im clearing cache) and for me it works only in the first time, after that the title stays static (maintains the value of the first try)

Comment: Yes, for me it works only in the first time too. but I solved this! In modal dialog page, add DA(page load) and set the javascript code 'apex.util.getTopApex().jQuery(".myDialog .ui-dialog-title").text($v("P44_TITLE") || '...');'

Comment: I have a similar selector on hand parent.$('.ui-dialog-title').closest('.ui-dialog--apex').find('.ui-dialog-title').text($v('P18_HEADER'));

Comment: ValérioCosta, Scott, Yours solutions is didn't worked for me, but I found another solution which one works: apex.util.getTopApex().jQuery(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "title", $v("P22_TITLE"));

Answer (score 0):

I made such dialogcreate js function.
It moves popup page Title to modal dialog title.
So, dynamic calculated title *&P51_TITLE.* would be applied automatically.

```
$(document).on("dialogcreate", ".ui-dialog--apex", function(e) {
  var lDialog = $(this);
  lDialog.find('iframe').on('load',function () {
      lDialog.children(".ui-dialog-content")
      .dialog("option", "title", $(this.contentDocument).find('title').html());
  });
});
```

I am very disappointed that something like this (or any other solution) do not work in apex modal pages by default!